# A question related to defination of 1-1 onto and invertible function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am trying some questions of previous years of my course and I am unable to solve this particular problem.

> Which of the following is necessarily true for a function $ f : X \to Y $?
> A. if $ f $ is injective, then there exists $ g : Y \to X $ such that $ f \big( g ( y ) \big) = y $ for all $ y \in Y $
> B. if $ f $ is surjective, then there exists $ g : Y \to X $ such that $ f \big( g ( y ) \big) = y $ for all $ y \in Y $
> C. if $ f $ is injective and $ Y $ is countable then $ X $ is finite
> D. if $ f $ is surjective and $ X $ is uncountable then $ Y $ is countably infinite

I think A or B would be true if function would be invertible (which is not given).

I think $f(x) = x$ when $Y$ is the set of rationals contradicts C.

For D, any inverse trigonometric function on its respective domain $\left[- \frac \pi 2 , \frac \pi 2 \right]$ or $[0,2\pi]$ would be sufficient.

So, what's the right answer? I contradicted all 4.

Answer given at back of paper is:

> Answer is given B.

Comment: I follow your counter-example to C. For D, I do not know why you are using a trig function instead of the same $f(x)=x$ example, but it looks like you are still getting a counter-example.  You have not given counter-examples to A or B, you have just said "it would be true if" but haven't shown example where it is not true.  You can find counter-examples to A but you will not be able to find any counter-examples to B.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think B requires the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your examples for C and D are correct.

For A just consider the function $f(n)=n+1$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and any function $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ fails $f(g(1))=1$.

For B you know that $f^{-1}(y)\neq\emptyset$ for any $y\in Y$. So there exists $x_{0}\in X$ such that $f(x_{0})=y$. Therefore you can define $g(y)=x_{0}$ and then $f(g(y))=f(x_{0})=y$.

Note that $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ with $f(1)=1$ and $f(n)=n-1$ for $n\geqslant2$ is not invertible and $g(n)=n+1$ satisfies $f(g(n))=n$ and so you have not contradicted B but added an unnecessary condition.

Comment: can you please explain that how I added an unnecessary condition in last paragraph of your answer?

Comment: When you say “I think A or B would be true if the function would be invertible”... being an invertible function is an unnecessary condition to hold the result you want to prove on B. I gave you an example of that. There are certainly examples where $f$ is invertible and holds the result on B.